# Could the 'underwater glider' concept be applied to a 4000-tonne, 80m submarine?

Tags: underwater, vehicles, solarpunk

Underwater gliders propel themselves through the water in an interesting way. They empty their tanks to float up, fill them to sink, repeat, going up and down rhythmically. But instead of just going up and down on the spot like idiots, they use wings to create forward movement from this up-down motion. This [PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810055753/https://www.ifremer.fr/lpo/gliders/donnees_tt/references/techno/4Gliders.pdf) says they "use lift on wings to convert this vertical velocity into forward motion". [The concept is illustrated well in this video](https://invidious.namazso.eu/watch?v=hmR4o2ueaK0).

[image]

This is much more energy-efficient than using propeller or jet-pump propulsion. "[seagliders operate with a high efficiency because the buoyancy engine only operates twice per cycle, once at the top and bottom of each yo, resulting in a low average propulsive power](https://earthzine.org/going-deep-to-go-far-how-dive-depth-impacts-seaglider-range/)" and the PDF already linked says "high efficiency is more easily achieved in the simpler hydrodynamic environment of wings". This is desirable for a solarpunk world I am building, where energy-efficiency is important.

That PDF again: *"A high operating speed would, of course, be desirable, but this conflicts with the primary goals of low cost, small size and long duration."* – supposing I didn't care about "low-cost" (it's a non-monetary world), and "small size" (I'm talking about a vessel big enough for a crew of dozens to live on), in that case would it be possible to have a large, reasonably fast underwater glider? (When I say 'reasonably fast'; existing models typically get about 1km/h, and that's ridiculous for a manned mission. 30km/h would be great, but 10 or even 7 would be fine. Energy-efficiency is more important to solarpunks than speed.)

My question is could this method of locomotion work on such a big, manned submarine? Would it fail to create enough thrust? Would it make the ride unacceptably bumpy?

The paper with DOI 10.1177/1729881420920534 says, in essence, that big rise-and-falls, say 1000m, will provide the most efficiency per unit distance travelled, and you'd go 10km forward for every yo. This would barely be noticed by people on board. That means about a 6° angle (tan6° is about 1/10)

Blended wings (where the whole body is a wing) are discussed [here](https://www.strikepod.com/chinese-research/) and in the paper with DOI 10.1080/17445302.2019.1611989 , which seems to assume 0.8m/s (i.e. 2.88km/h)

**Note1**: Stealth is unimportant; people always bring up stealth when submarines are being discussed.

**Note2**: It will have an auxiliary active engine (hydrogen-fuelled) for emergencies, sprinting, surface propulsion, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with propellers? Have you done a back-of-the-envelope calculation to understand how the (in)efficiency of this method of propulsion compares to plain ordinary propellers or flapping wings? (And why would you expect anybody to click on a link going to invidious.namazso.eu, which is nothing but a leech feeding on YouTube?

Comment: "[Gliders have an intrinsic advantage in transport efficiency over conventional prop-driven autonomous underwater vehicles ( AUV s) due to the simpler vortex dynamics of a wing versus a propeller.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-16649-0_12)"

Comment: As for your second question, it is 20× lighter on RAM, no exaggeration.

Comment: A propeller **is** a set of rotary wings. Saying that wings have simpler dynamics than propellers is like saying that liquids have simpler dynamics than wine. If the dynamics gets too complicated you can always make the propeller larger and slower. (But simplifying the calculations is most usually not a worthwhile design goal.) (And for the lighter or RAM, Ublock Origin exists for a reason.)

Comment: When you ask "would it fail to create enough thrust" we need more information on what amount of thrust is "enough".  Enough to slowly cross an area of more-or-less "still" oceanic water?  Move against a significant current?  Allow fine enough control to dock at a wharf at the end of a voyage?  More detail needed.

Comment: I think I get it... You want a vehicle to glide underwater as a sailplane glides through air, and use updrafts to soar. Sad to say, the [largest such vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberdade_class_underwater_glider) is not very large.

Comment: @AlexP Not updrafts. The device in the linked video generates up-down motion by pumping ballast. It converts the up-down to forward motion using fins.

Comment: "Unacceptably bumpy" depends on the passengers. And how fast they wanted to go. That would require a lot of engineering design to get a handle on. A good answer to this question might require person-years of effort. One thing is, it would be pretty bad at getting you into dock. So you would need other motors or help from a tug boat or some such.

Comment: "Stealth is unimportant" begs the question, why a sub? Running underwater slows you down. Subs go faster on the surface. So why are you underwater? You need a reason to be down here. That reason limits what is feasible to do.

Comment: How does it beg the question? I didn't assume the conclusion in the premise.

Comment: @wokopa it begs the question because you've excluded the reason most people would assume why they're doing this. If not stealth then why are they doing it? The mission they're on limits how we can solve the problems this idea presents. Are these marine biologists? Carnival riders? Yacht club racers? Give us a clue.

Comment: They could do fun Cousteau stuff, chat with their whale buddies. Why did The Beatles live in a submarine?

Comment: @wokopa to sell albums.

Comment: Stealth is the one and only reason why submarines exist. If stealth is not important, a 4000 ton sailing ship will be very much cheaper amd very much safer than a submarine; and also very much faster than a submarine which does not have nuclear propulsion.

Comment: @AlexP well no. Subs are also used to explore deep sea life. But that's small subs that mostly go up and down. Not so much with the forward propulsion.

Comment: This should (and will) be a hobbyists toy

Answer (score 4):

Ok, after a few more hours research, I think I'm ready to answer my own question.

## Yes, and bigger is actually better

The best paper on this is *Jenkins, S. A., & D’Spain, G. (2016). Autonomous Underwater Gliders. Springer Handbook of Ocean Engineering, 301–322. doi:10.1007/978-3-319-16649-0_12*

It says in the abstract/summary, as one of the main points:

- "Increases in efficiency can be
  obtained by: 1. Increasing the loaded mass (with larger buoyancy engines) and increasing the overall size of
  the glider, which increases the glider’s speed
  and maintain sufficiently high Reynold’s num-
  bers to avoid the drag crisis."

That's music to my ears. It's saying the bigger they are, the faster and more efficient they are. Somebody mentioned the [Liberdade class gliders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberdade_class_underwater_glider), which outperform the competition and are also bigger.

In the section on 'Size effects', the same paper goes on to say:

- "The minimum specific energy consumption from(12.13) decreases as V =4 b , i. e., it decreases with increasing net buoyancy. Because net buoyancy is somefraction nb of the total vehicle volume V0 , where Vb D nbV0 , bigger buoyancy-driven vehicles generally are more transport efficient. Actually, surveys of natural and man-made fliers by [12.12] and [12.14] demonstrate that specific energy consumption monotonically decreases across 12 orders of magnitude of size increase. This size advantage is accentuated in an underwater glider because the buoyancy volume factor, nb , increases with increasing vehicle volume approximately as nb  1:2  105V7=6 0 , due to economies of scale in packing efficiency [12.7]. Larger nb permits higher glide speeds (speed increases as the square root of the increase in net buoyancy) and higher wing section Reynolds numbers, which results in higher wing section lift-to-drag ratios"

More music to my ears! Big ones are not only more efficient, they are faster too! And this effect endures over 12 orders of magnitude, so yes we could scale up the man-portable drones that now exist to something that houses dozens of crew.

---

Some details:

The Liberdade vehicles are 1400lb, or, in freedom units, 0.6356 tonnes. A 4000-tonne vehicle is 6293 times the size. (It may seems I'm confusing volume with mass here, but that's valid because all submarines have the same density, i.e. the density of seawater)

A blended wing design (the wing is the body) is best. At first I was resistant to this because it's too exotic, but the more I think about it, the better it seems. It's not that much more high-tech to build a wing than a tube; it doesn't require the complex fly-by-wire stuff of airborne flying wings. Cigar-shaped submarines are pretty boring & ugly let's face it. It is closer to nature, in particular manta rays, but even whales have tapered foil-shaped bodies. The living quarters are not narrow and that's more comfortable.

[image]

The "speed increases as the square root of the increase in net buoyancy", which is to say if you double the size of the ballast tanks, you increase speed 41%. If you quadruple the size of the ballast tanks, you double speed. Obviously that cuts into space you could have otherwise used for living space, hydrogen fuel, equipment. We can go faster if we lose our ping-pong table.

This diagram shows the relationship of glider speed to ballast tank size (the four arcs) and angle.

[image]

35° is the fastest angle, which will be uncomfortable. 4° is the most efficient. The tradeoffs between a comfortable flat angle, speed, and efficiency are something the crew can decide as they steer. They can sleep in hanging beds while the boat dives at steeper angles:

[image]

It's not a constant up-and-down bouncy turbulence. It's smooth-but-slanted and stays the same for a fairly long time.

A second reference supporting the scale effects is: https://escholarship.org/uc/item/1c28t6bb – The Table E.1 shows that for each class, the bigger versions are better. Chapter 10 is entirely devoted to discussing the effects of size on gliders, what the question was about.

I have a detailed design for a 25-man, 4000-tonne blended with submarine worked out now. I won't bore you with it unless one person asks me.

Comment: The last calculation is wrong. You need to sub in 1 in place of the 6293 and compare the ratio of results. You're comparing 0.569 to 0.0034, so it's 160 times faster, which as a matter of maths makes sense given that it's almost a simple square root relationship with 6293 as an input ratio, but as a matter of  real life performance seems unlikely. I'm assuming that the other expressions are correct uncritically.

Comment: I'm just gonna delete the last calculation. If someone wants to read the section on 'Size effects' in the paper with DOI 10.1007/978-3-319-16649-0_12 and calculate how much speed you'd gain from a 6293× increase, that would be appreciated/upvoted.

Comment: I'm always happy when people figure out solutions to their own questions and share them here. Wish I could upvote twice for the freedom units.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that would work. This could easily be done with oversized ballast tanks. I have no doubt that current submarines take advantage of this from time to time.

More likely, they would have numerous piston chambers that sucked water in at the surface and pushed it out as jets at the bottom of the ship's sawtooth path.

Issues I can think of:

- the entire floor would be pitching forward and back with every shift. Maybe you'd put the bunks and control center on gimbles.
- you'd incur an immense amount of wear and tear as the hull was constantly being pressurized and depressurized.
- You'd need a significant depth to operate.
- You'd still need normal propulsion to get into and out of port.

The speed would be based on the size of the ballast tanks. Larger tanks = more buoyancy = faster gliding.

Comment: These are all good points, I think I can call them all annoyances rather than dealbreakers. 1) The pitch would be about 6° and change less than once per hour. 2) I had already decided that these vehicles would be made of composites, not metal, so that it could be made flexible so that the sea pressure would be within the [fatigue limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatigue_limit). [This](https://www.theengineer.co.uk/content/news/composite-parts-for-subs) mentions a sandwich structure for sub hulls which could be flex outside, strong inside.

Comment: 3) You wouldn't ***need*** depth to operate, just to operate in the most efficient mode. 4) Yes on auxiliary engines.

Comment: @wokopa, The 6 degree pitching would be less than most sea-going boats experience due to surface turbulence, so I wouldn't worry about it. I think you got this.

Comment: It's not nothing though: more slopey than a wheelchair ramp

Comment: Yup. And that's just the normal. Serious dives can get to 30 degrees or more, although usually they limit themselves to 20. That's why I was suggesting gimbals. Especially for dinning areas.

Comment: Stuff falling over every now and then, I'm happy with that as part of the worldbuilding. The sort of everyday annoyance that adds flavour. The 30° dives could be timed when most of the crew are sleeping.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for the ship to pitch; the ship can stay perfectly level and the wings can rotate as needed.

Comment: @AlexP the surface of a plane's fuselage is not excluded while calculating aerodynamics, here the issue is 770x worse, so no, tilting the sub's hull is mandatory.

Comment: Re: fatigue, there's no real reason why the ship has to have a huge vertical shift. After all, you only need to change density from sea * 0.99 to sea * 1.01 and back...if slow speeds (or at least, acceleration/deceleration) don't matter. Low speeds might be the best way to mitigate energy costs rather than large vertical distances (and given that you have to expel water versus pressure, is almost certainly better, unless you're cheating by holding lots of high P compressed air to displace the ballast).

Comment: You could always make a port just for subs like this. An aircraft carrier sized vessel or an oil rig could serve as a floating port.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant, What you're describing sounds more like "cargo ship" kind of "speed isn't important." My impression was that OP meant something more like the "not actually in a hurry" kind.

Comment: @RobertRapplean You're right, I reread the question and a high speed features prominently. Grr, shouldn't skim then comment, I know better than that.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking on this - I think the problem you are going to hit is one of displacement and momentum firstly and a pretty major safety issue secondly.

As you get larger, you displace more water, you can only increase your buoyancy so much for a given volume and displacement - which provides an upper limit to how much up-thrust you can generate. Will that be enough to overcome the momentum of the ship? I don't have access to complicated Fluid Dynamics software - but my gut tells me that at a certain point, it's easier for the water to flow around the wing, than it is to generate a forward motion.

The second issue is that without an engine - if you have any problem with your Ballast system - you are probably dead.

I'm thinking of the case of the USS San Francisco - SSN-711 when she booped an underwater mountain running at Flank speed.  IIRC, because of the damage to her front ballast tanks, she had to keep her nose up using the rear diveplanes and the Propulsion from her engine.

If you have no engine, and you have an issue with buoyancy - your only option is to throw the [chicken switches](https://americanhistory.si.edu/subs/operating/attackcenter/controlstation/emergblow.html) and hope that gets you to the surface, you have no other means of propulsion of getting to the surface. And once you've done an Emergency Blow - that's it.

So, for small Unmanned subs - I think it's possible, but for larger Manned subs - I think you are going to have issues with overcoming the momentum on the boat and simply put - such a design would be massively unsafe.

Comment: Ooo, chicken switches. It makes sense that they would exist, but I hadn't heard of them.

Comment: "Major safety issue" is what makes it fun!